# magento ajax not working on frontend

Tags: ajax, magento

I created a block path is : **local\Attribute\Layout\Controllers\ProductController** code is

class Attribute_Layout_ProductController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

```
  public function ajaxDataAction()
  {

     echo 'ajax controller';
  }
```

}

And in etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>

<modules>
    <Attribute_Layout>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Attribute_Layout>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <attribute_layout>
            <class>Attribute_Layout_Block</class>
        </attribute_layout>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <layout>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Attribute_Layout</module>
                <frontName>layout</frontName>
            </args>
        </layout>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <attribute_layout module="Attribute_Layout">
                <file>attribute_layout.xml</file>
            </attribute_layout>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

And design\frontend\default\shirt_cust\layout\attribute_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="1.0">

<default>
<attribute_layout_product_ajaxData>
       <block type="layout/product" name="root" output="toHtml" template="attribute_layout/product.phtml" />
</attribute_layout_product_ajaxData>    

</default>

</layout>
```

And ajax template in design\frontend\default\shirt_cust\template\product.phtml

```
             $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo $this->getUrl('layout/product/ajaxData') ?>',
        type:'post',
        data: {id:31},
        success:function(result) {
            $('#res_html').html(result);
        }
    });
```

My ajax url in local localhost/shirt/layout/product/ajaxData is working fine
but not working in my server. path is: 162.144.13.7/o/tailorcustmize/layout/product/ajaxData

Getting 404 error

I tried anything but didn't find any solution please help me to solve this problem

What is the problem in this code please suggest anything. My server is linux.

Answer (score 0):

etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Attribute_Layout>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Attribute_Layout>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <layout>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Attribute_Layout</module>
                <frontName>layout</frontName>
            </args>
        </layout>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <layout>
                <file>attribute_layout.xml</file>
            </layout>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <layout>
            <class>Attribute_Layout_Block</class>
        </layout>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

And design\frontend\default\shirt_cust\layout\attribute_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.0.1">
    <layout_product_ajaxData>
       <block type="layout/product" name="root" output="toHtml" template="attribute_layout/product.phtml" />
    </layout_product_ajaxData>
</layout>
```